# codeigniter Rest_controller output bad format

Tags: php, codeigniter

Whatever the output format selected some **"\r\r\r"** appears at the beginning of output. With **XML** format, it generates a bad format error because **<?xml**  is not the first chars.
Looks like the **"\r"** has been sended before the response directive and :

> ```
>          $this->response($liste, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
> ```

a die("test") before the parent::__construct(); is ok but after I receive "\r\r\rtest" so something in Rest_controller output the \r???

All the restfull API is working perfectly except that issue.
thank you for your precious help

I have found the reason. It comes from the CI_Controller when loading the librairies : you must avoid to close PHP at the end of all librairies and includes like that :

> - } /* End of file module_xxx.php */ /* Location: ./application/librairies/module_xx/module_xxx.php */

Comment: So you answered your own question then?  If so, put your answer in the answer box below and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason. It comes from the CI_Controller when loading the librairies : you must avoid to close PHP at the end of all librairies and includes like that :

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Module_xxx extends Module_yyy {

-
    }
/* End of file module_xxx.php */
/* Location: ./application/librairies/module_xx/module_client.php */
```

Codeigniter loader loads the librairies with includes statements and send at that time all relevant lines after the PHP closure (in fact this is PHP involved). Best way would be to avoid PHP closure in all files.

Comment: The issue is pointed out in the CodeIgniter manual: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/styleguide.html#php_closing_tag